# Custom toggler?

Tags: emacs, elisp, state

I want to have toggler which would add/remove ".. " (there's a space -- but I can't make it more pronounced) string in front of every line above (point). Here's my best bet:

```
(defun rst-comment-above (Point)
  (interactive "d")
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char 1)
    (cond

     ((numberp (get this-command 'state))
      ((replace-regexp "^\\.\\. " "" nil (point) (get this-command 'state)))
      (put this-command 'state ""))

     (t
     (replace-regexp "^" ".. " nil (point) Point)
     (put this-command 'state Point))
)))
```

it works for the first time, but for the second it says:

```
(invalid-function
 (replace-regexp "^\\.\\. " "" nil (point) (get this-command (quote state))))
```

**Edit**:

@user4815162342:

So I comment the thing above:

[image: I comment the thing above]

Then I insert new lines:

[image: I insert new lines]

Then I want to uncomment the thing, and I get:

[image: upon uncommenting the thing, and I get]

But probably its not that important. I do not generally enter anything in the commented area. I just note that the issue. What is some what more important -- is to store the `'state` of the given file across the sessions. Is it hard to implement?

Comment: Instead of (goto-char 1) I recommend `(goto-char (point-min))`.

Comment: @Stefan: Ok. Although I do not use narrowing for now.

Comment: I now see what you mean. I've updated my answer to handle this case, and fixed another bug. Please try the new version.

Comment: @Adobe: If you get used to using `1` instead of `point-min` you'll get bitten sooner or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from the extra set of parentheses on the line where you call `replace-regexp`. That line should be:

```
(replace-regexp "^\\.\\. " "" nil (point) (get this-command 'state))
```

There are several other problems with your code.

1. Storing the current value of point doesn't work well because you add
   characters to the buffer, which makes the point move forward.  This makes
   (once the above syntax error is fixed) the function miss the last several
   instances of "..".

   - The fix is to store the point marker.
2. You should be using `(point-min)` instead of hard-coding the buffer
   beginning to 1, or your code will fail to work when buffer narrowing is in
   effect.
3. Finally, `replace-regexp`, as its documentation states, is not meant to be
   called from Lisp programs.

Here is a revised version of your function:

```
(defun rst-comment-above ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((pm (point-marker))
        (prev-marker (get this-command 'rst-prev-marker)))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (cond ((null prev-marker)
             (while (< (point) pm)
               (insert "..")
               (forward-line 1))
             (put this-command 'rst-prev-marker pm))
            (t
             (while (< (point) prev-marker)
               (when (looking-at "^\\.\\.")
                 (replace-match ""))
               (forward-line 1))
             (put this-command 'rst-prev-marker nil))))))
```

Comment: can you pick a username?  Any random word is find, it makes it easier for others to refer to your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, the improved formatting makes the answer a lot clearer.

Comment: `point-marker` does hold the right position -- if You insert new chars to the commented text -- but not new lines. While `set-mark` and `register-to-point` does: even after I input some new lines above those marks -- the marks point to the right `point`. I can see it with `anything-mark-ring` (or `icicle-goto-marker`) and `point-to-register` respectively. But all of them are interactive and I can't see a way to utilize them for the purpose. Do You thing something can be done? Anyway thanks for You code and criticism. It is useful to leave a redundant pair of paranthesis here and there...

Comment: A marker tracks buffer insertions above its position, regardless of whether newlines or other characters are inserted. For example, if you go to the end of a non-empty buffer, evaluate `M-: (setq a (point-marker))`, then add a newline at the beginning, the marker value, printed with `M-: a`, will increment. How is the command misbehaving for you, exactly?

Comment: To answer my own question: the function was misbehaving because the `looking-at` check would terminate the loop, so if a single new line was inserted between the buffer beginning and the point, uncommenting would cease at that line. Furthermore, the uncommenting command would always uncomment up to the current point, rather than to the stored position. The revised answer fixes these issues.

Comment: Thanks -- I'm using the updated version. Beeing able to modify freely the commented area is very usufull, actually. And the uncommented state can be restored by a single replace-regexp command. So it's not a problem in a way.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you don't use `M-;` in `rst-mode`?

Comment: @Adobe: works for me.  If it doesn't, please report it as a bug.